# Problem on Poisson distribution: Probability that 5th call will arrive between 8:10 to 8:20 am

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Calls arriving at a telephone exchange follow a Poisson distribution with an average of 3 calls every 10 minutes. If the telephone exchange opens at 8:00 am, what is the probability that the 5th call arrives between 8:10 am to 8:20 am?

Here I am creating two events:

**Event A:** Number of calls between 8:00 am to 8:20 am is $\geq 5$

**Event B:** Number of calls between 8:00 am to 8:10 am is $\leq 4$

Then the probability that the 5th call will arrive between 8:10 to 8:20 is $P(A \cap B)$.

Now I have found $P(A)=0.71494$ and $P(B)=0.81526$.

How do I find $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: Consider Event B as Number of calls between $8:00$ am to $8:10$ am being $ \geq 5$. Then the desired probability is $P(A) - P(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to handle independent or mutually distinct events so you can multiply or add their probabilities.

Here you have three mutually distinct events, so you can use addition and subtraction

- Number of calls between 8:00 am to 8:20 am is $\le 4$: this has probability $1- P(A)$ in your terms
- Number of calls between 8:00 am to 8:10 am is $\ge 5$: this has probability $1- P(B)$ in your terms
- Fifth call is between 8:10 am and 8:20 am: this has probability $1-(1- P(A))-(1- P(B)) = P(A)+ P(B)-1$ in your terms

In effect the argument is that $$P(A \cup B)= P(A)+P(B) -P(A \cap B)$$ so   $$P(A \cap B)= P(A)+P(B) -P(A \cup B)$$ $$P(A \cap B)= P(A)+P(B) -(1 - P(A^c \cap B^c))$$ and in this case $$P(A^c \cap B^c)=0$$